# Registering providers in the angular module or components

Tags: angular, angular-services

In John Papa's very good [course on Angular 2](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-first-look/table-of-contents) on pluralsight, he recommends as a rule of thumb that providers be registered in `@NgModule` rather than in `@Components`, because there is rarely the need to hide providers from other components. In Angular 1 where all providers needed to be registered at the module level there is no debate about this. But what situations would warrant breaking this rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register in each component, it will every time create `new object for that service`, when the component's instance will be created. So if you need for every component to have it's own service, provide them in the components.

If you need an `singleton service`, so provide it in the module and all components of that module will get the same instance of the service.